# Is it necessary to have a Firewall in Ubuntu?

Tags: security, firewall

I was wondering if a Firewall could give some more security, and if yes which one would you recommend.

Comment: See [Do I Need a Firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DoINeedAFirewall)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you are doing, but when you just use your Ubuntu machine for e-mail, browsing and text editing I would say no. In case you have services running like SSH or FTP you might consider installing a firewall manager, for example `ufw`.

Comment: Thanks, my father wants to do some home banking, and I didn't know if it was safe.